# Search images taken by camera in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, search

I just lost all the files on my computer. Luckily using PhotoRec, I was able to recover a huge amount of files, including 200,000 images. Sadly this includes almost every photo that I've deleted, including all the images that get downloaded as browser cache, so that vast majority are junk.

In Windows 7 you search by Date modifed and Size (the two filters given in the drop down), and also Kind. Is there any filter that can let me search for images for images from a specific camera (iPhone), I found one photo from my phone and The Camera Model meta tag is filled out correctly, so can I search for all images with this meta tag?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out you can just use `camera:` or `cameramodel:`

> [http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20101129070109/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx)

Comment: I was in the middle of typing up a longer answer.  Glad you could recover your photos/memories.

Comment: Sorry :/ If you haven't lost it, you could still post, the more info the better?

Comment: Nah, I was gonna post roughly the same thing.  Mainly, through the details view, turn on column, blah blah blah.  The Advanced query option is much much faster, but that tends to intimidate new users.  **I must type something at a prompt!!??**

Comment: The link has changed. Would please guys explain more about this.

Comment: Yes, the link is broken :(